# Incorrect syntax error using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here is the statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'CRM_ValidateUser @p0, @p1, @p2',
    N'@p0 nvarchar(5),@p1 nvarchar(4),@p2 int',@p0=N'login',@p1=N'pass',@p2=15
```

Why am I getting this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CRM_ValidateUser'.

Comment: Can reproduce the different behaviour between 2005/2008 for following proc definition. `CREATE PROC CRM_ValidateUser @p1 nvarchar(4)=NULL,@p0 nvarchar(5)=NULL,@p2 int=NULL AS SELECT 1`. The 2005 version only works when no parameters are passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say EXEC in case any other commands are transmitted as part of the batch. In this case, it will be parameter definitions, so the batch actually sent back into SQL Server will be something like:

```
DECLARE @p0 NVARCHAR(5);
...
CRM_ValidateUser ...
```

And this is why your error message occurs. `EXEC` can only be omitted if the stored procedure call is the *first* statement in the batch, and IMHO should never be excluded anyway. Try:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC CRM_ValidateUser...
```

Also a good idea to specify schema prefix.

Comment: I'm not sure, are you positive the code is identical? Proper syntax to call a stored procedure is `EXEC procedurename`... why do you want to continue doing it the wrong way, just because it works in some cases?

Comment: haha It has nothing to do with Right and wrong it has to do with 1 requires a release and one doesn't.  and yes I am sure

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @p0 NVARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @p1 NVARCHAR(4);
DECLARE @p2 INT;

SET @p0 =N'login';

SET @p1 = N'pass';

SET @p2 = 15;
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'CRM_ValidateUser', @p0, @p1, @p2;
```

Comment: This is wrong too. `sp_executesql` requires parameter definitions as the second argument. Even if you add those you'll *still* get the same error. Does anybody try their "answers" before posting them?